# Jackson: Class B extends A. Class X extends Y. A has a List of X. How can I deserialize Y and get a List of Ys in it?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have a class `A` which has a `List` of `X`s.  I have a class `B` which extends `A` and a class `Y` that extends `X`.  All classes are concrete.  I would like it so that if I use Jackson to deserialize `A`, it has a list of `X`s, but if I deserialize `B`, I get a list of `Y`s.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in the `B` class:

```
@Override
@JsonDeserialize(//use whatever you need here)
public void setX(List<List<X>> xs) {
    super.setX(xs);
}
```